# Why do women not like Chandler Bing?

Tags: character, analysis, friends

In the series **Friends**, in numerous occasions, it's implied that women generally don't like Chandler Bing and that he has a very hard time even finding a woman for a date. Also, there are a few incidents where Phoebe said that she actually didn't like Chandler.

My question is:

Why don't women like Chandler? **Even in general social terms?**

Why is it very hard for him to find a girlfriend?

Comment: I don't remember him having good flirt skills either. That scene in the locked-up phone booth with the bubblegum :D

Comment: Ross was the same. in that episode with pizza girl with short hair? thing is Chandler was worst among them and I cant find why

Answer (score 15):

In the simplistic world of TV, women like strong, confident men.  Chandler is neither of these.  In his own words (to Janice) he's "hopeless and awkward and desperate for love" (The one with the metaphorical tunnel)

Let's not forget that one of the running jokes throughout the series was that Chandler was gay.  That wouldn't stop women liking him but until they get to know him (hard to do when he's always joking around and never lets people see the real him), they wouldn't consider him a suitable partner.

Not only this but he's never been too good with the protocols of talking to women.  As Rachel once said when she thought he was gay "but then you spent my birthday talking to my breasts so I figured maybe not"

If you look at the relationships he had in the show, not many of them that ended were his fault.  Janice notwithstanding, he had Aurora who was married and had other boyfriends, Kathy who cheated on him, Joanna (Rachel's boss) where he chose his friend over a partner.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't Chandler look gay at first to people who meet him? I mean at first impression he had that "Quality" that expresses him as a homosexual character. Also he is not very good with women, flirting and even at his past, like high school and college, he couldn't actually connect with girls. In one episode he says to Monica that he was with only one woman.

Considering all those facts I think that Chandler may not seem very attractive or didn't leave a good impression at other people. That could be the reason.

Comment: Joey answering a thing about chandler. could it be any nicer? :)